# Adding popover to navbar dropdown item

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, popover

I want to add a popover to an item, which is in a dropdown menu, which is in a navbar.

So on hover the popover should appear.

Can somebody help me creating this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the following code to display popover on Dropdown menus, and here is the working [fiddle](http://bootply.com/94629)

**HTML**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
  </div>

  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li id="ex1"><a href="#">Example 1</a></li>
          <li id="ex2"><a href="#">Example 2</a></li>
          <li id="ex3"><a href="#">Example 3</a></li>
          <li id="ex5"><a href="#">Example 4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>
```

**jquery**

```
$(function () {
                var showPopover = function () {
                    $(this).popover('show');
                }
                , hidePopover = function () {
                    $(this).popover('hide');
                };
        $('#ex1').popover({
                    content: 'An Example1 popover',
                    trigger: 'hover',
                    placement:'top'
                })
        $('#ex2').popover({
                    content: 'An Example2 popover',
                    trigger: 'hover',
                    placement:'top'
                }) 

        $('#ex3').popover({
                    content: 'An Example3 popover',
                    trigger: 'hover',
                    placement:'top'
                })         

});
```